# How to use slf4j logger instead of builtin Liferay DXP 7.2 logger in mvc-portlet?

Tags: liferay, slf4j, liferay-dxp, slf4j-api, liferay-7.2

I can't figure out how to turn off the default logger and use slf4j instead of the default in Liferay DXP 7.2 mvc-portlet. A working example would be great.

I have already tried:

[Implementing Logging](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017883592-Implementing-Logging-)

[How to disable XML Log Files in Liferay 7.x](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/how-to-disable-xml-log-files-in-7-x)

[Using SLF4J and Liferay Logging Framework in custom plugins](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/using-slf4j-and-liferay-logging-framework-in-custom-plugins/maximized)

[Liferay Logging is Dead! Long Live Liferay Logging!](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-logging-is-dead-long-live-liferay-logging-)

[Github: dnebing/slf4j-liferay](https://github.com/dnebing/slf4j-liferay)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are few example available on Liferay documentation, blogs and github. See below links.

https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017883592-Implementing-Logging-
https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-logging-is-dead-long-live-liferay-logging-
https://github.com/dnebing/slf4j-liferay